# Modify userInput on submit

Tags: javascript

I need help with this javascript, if a user inputs anything in the filed the field will print that value, but i want to modify specific part of the value. users are going to submit image urls which have a specific string that i need to modify.

For instance user input something like: **http://www.domain.com/photos/1.jpg**

The result should be: **http://www.domain.com/photos-d/1.jpg**

**Here is the code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = userInput;
}
</script>

<input type='text' id='userInput' onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value='Enter Image URL';" onclick="if(this.value == 'Enter Image URL') this.value='';"/>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Generate'/>

<p>Output: <a id='result'></a> </p>
```

your help will be much appreciated - Thanks,

Comment: is it that you always have to add '-d' or there are some other cases too ??

Comment: only -d part will be added nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = userInput.replace("/photos/", "/photos-d/");
}
</script>

<input type='text' id='userInput' placeholder="Enter Image URL"/>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Generate'/>

<p>Output: <a id='result'></a> </p>
```

P.S.: You could use [placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) (html5 supported) instead of the onblur and onclick events.

Comment: Thanks gopi1410, let me test this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could have http://www.domain.com/photos-d/ as a label before the input instead of asking the user to type this part. If he only needs to type in the image file name there will be no need to change the input field.

Comment: URL will be unique every time, but /photos/ part will be static. and that i need to modify with /photos-d/

Comment: @XeBii do you mean that the domain may change but the /photos/ part must always be there to be changed to /photos-d/ ?

Comment: yes Frederik, and i have found the solution provided by gopi1410

Answer (score 0):

so basically you want to modify a string based on occurance of certain string in it viz .jpg.

so firstly, see whether your userInput needs to be modified or not.

so do this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText2(){
        var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
         if(userInput.indexOf('.jpg') !== -1){

           userInput = userInput.replace('photos','photos-d');
         }
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = userInput;
    }
    </script>
```

so basically you need efficient [string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/method-like-string-contains-in-javascript) algos and regex to detect keywords

Comment: Appreciate your help Manish Mishra, but the answered which i have marked is much more simple. thank you

Comment: :).both are the same thing, mine with a check tht you don't replace your url everytime, only when it contains an image url.that's wat u asked right? anyways